# How to sort items in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, sorting, objectlistview

I am using [`ObjectListView`](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html) to display a list of items. However columns are not getting sorted when I click on the column headers.

Please refer the code pasted below:

```
public class Stock
{
    public Stock()
    {
    }

    public Stock(string name, double lastPrice, double greenTrend, double redTrend, double lastGreenValue, double lastRedValue)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.LastPrice = lastPrice;
        this.GreenTrend = greenTrend;
        this.RedTrend = redTrend;
        this.LastGreenValue = lastGreenValue;
        this.LastRedValue = lastRedValue;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private string name;

    public double LastPrice
    {
        get { return lastPrice; }
        set { lastPrice = value; }
    }
    private double lastPrice;

    public double GreenTrend
    {
        get { return greenTrend; }
        set { greenTrend = value; }
    }
    private double greenTrend;

    public double RedTrend
    {
        get { return redTrend; }
        set { redTrend = value; }
    }
    private double redTrend;

    public double LastGreenValue
    {
        get { return lastGreenValue; }
        set { lastGreenValue = value; }
    }
    private double lastGreenValue;

    public double LastRedValue
    {
        get { return lastRedValue; }
        set { lastRedValue = value; }
    }
    private double lastRedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found the answer. When I changed the `ShowGroups` property of `ObjectListView` to false, sorting worked. This was set to true by default!

Comment: Thanks! Why this isn't the default option I don't know!

Answer (score 4):

I made a few code changes in `ObjectListView` (version 2.6.0) to enable sorting by non-groupable columns even when `ShowGoups` is set to `True`.

This way it's possible to have a normal sorting for columns with the `Groupable` property set to `False` and still be able to group the items when sorting by a column which has the `Groupable` property set to True.

Make the following changes to get this behavior.

1. In the `PostProcessRows()` method, exchange this code (around line `7729`):

   ```
   if (this.ShowGroups) {
       foreach (ListViewGroup group in this.Groups) {
           foreach (OLVListItem olvi in group.Items) {
               ...
   ```

   by this:

   ```
   if (this.ShowGroups && ((this.LastSortColumn != null) && this.LastSortColumn.Groupable)) {
       foreach (ListViewGroup group in this.Groups) {
           foreach (OLVListItem olvi in group.Items) {
               ...
   ```
2. In the `DoSort()` method, exchange this code (around `7391`):

   ```
   if (!args.Handled) {
       // Sanity checks
       if (args.ColumnToSort != null && args.SortOrder != SortOrder.None) {
           if (this.ShowGroups)
               this.BuildGroups(args.ColumnToGroupBy, args.GroupByOrder, args.ColumnToSort, args.SortOrder,
                   args.SecondaryColumnToSort, args.SecondarySortOrder);
           else if (this.CustomSorter != null)
               this.CustomSorter(args.ColumnToSort, args.SortOrder);
           else
               this.ListViewItemSorter = new ColumnComparer(args.ColumnToSort, args.SortOrder,
                   args.SecondaryColumnToSort, args.SecondarySortOrder);
       }
   }
   ```

   by this:

   ```
   if (!args.Handled) {
       // Sanity checks
       if (args.ColumnToSort != null && args.SortOrder != SortOrder.None) {
           if (this.ShowGroups && args.ColumnToGroupBy.Groupable)
               this.BuildGroups(args.ColumnToGroupBy, args.GroupByOrder, args.ColumnToSort, args.SortOrder,
                   args.SecondaryColumnToSort, args.SecondarySortOrder);
           else if (this.CustomSorter != null)
               this.CustomSorter(args.ColumnToSort, args.SortOrder);
           else
           {
               this.Groups.Clear();
               this.ListViewItemSorter = new ColumnComparer(args.ColumnToSort, args.SortOrder,
                   args.SecondaryColumnToSort, args.SecondarySortOrder);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now it'll be possible to sort regular and groupable columns all in one `ObjectListView` combined.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Igespee's answer, if you use Search on a column that doesn't have groups and are crashing you also have to change the following two lines. Keep in mind more changes like this are probably necessary (like the GetLastItemInDisplayOrder function right before), but these will at least prevent it from crashing everytime a key is pressed.

@@ -3948,7 +3948,7 @@ namespace BrightIdeasSoftware

```
    /// <param name="n"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual OLVListItem GetNthItemInDisplayOrder(int n) {
--      if (!this.ShowGroups)
++      if (!this.ShowGroups || this.Groups.Count==0)
            return this.GetItem(n);

        foreach (ListViewGroup group in this.Groups) {
```

@@ -3969,7 +3969,7 @@ namespace BrightIdeasSoftware

```
    /// <param name="itemIndex"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual int GetDisplayOrderOfItemIndex(int itemIndex) {
--     if (!this.ShowGroups)
++     if (!this.ShowGroups || this.Groups.Count == 0)
            return itemIndex;
```